# "Всем это очевидно" или "для всех это очевидно"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: *всем это очевидно* или *для всех это очевидно*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это зависит от наличия или отсутствия "всех": первый вариант для отсутствующих или абстрактных (гипотетических) "всех" меньше подходит.

Comment: *Это зависит от наличия или отсутствия "всех"* -  это как? О_о

Comment: В выражении "всем это очевидно" акцентируется реакция "всех": они как бы имеют возможность подтвердить сказанное, и по форме высказывания в этом есть некоторый вызов. Во втором варианте акцент на свойства самого утверждения: оно таково, что в случае чего "любой с этим утверждением согласится" - это не относится к какой-либо конкретной группе лиц. Допускаю, что не все различают эти варианты.

Comment: Спасибо за смысловые нюансы, Alex_ander!

Comment: Alex_ander, я допускаю, что вы просто не подумали, когда писали. ))) У слова "все"/"всех"/"всем" не семантики "никого" и быть не может. При этом сказанное в одинаковой сткпкни относится и к "всех", и к "всем". Поэтому ваши рассуждения в не просто сугубо личное мнение, оно еще и как мнение не сформулировано. Просто нет причин разделять по такому принципу.

Answer (score 3):

Как по мне, перед нами такие предложения, где семантика одинаковая, а грамматически они оформлены по-разному. Оба варианта встречаются в современной речи, и я не вижу никаких причин называть какой-то из них неправильным. Очевидно (кому?) всем. Очевидно (для кого?) для всех. Ну всё же правильно.

Comment: Спасибо, Tagirix!

Answer (score 1):

Я не вижу принципиальных различий. Обе фразы правильны и семантически равнозначны. Даже стилистически эквивалентны.

Разговор о каких-то "несуществующих всех" от Alex_ander мне непонятны изначально, как это *"все, которые никого"?*  Возможно, есть какой-то слабый оттенок направленности высказывания, но очень субъективный. Типа того, что "для всех" - это когда в очевидности пришлось убеждать, а "всем" - сами дошли или априорно понимали. Что тут добавить, не знаю даже.

Comment: Благодарю, behemothus!

Answer (score 1):

Разница в смысловых оттенках.

Обычно предложные конструкции, в которых отношения между словами выражаются не только падежным окончанием, но и предлогом, имеют более конкретный характер, связь между словами уточняется. 
Такое же различие в смысловых оттенках (более конкретное значение предложных конструкций) находим в приводимых ниже парах:

> Интересный всем – интересный для всех, нужный многим – нужный для многих, полезный детям – полезный для детей, понятный каждому – понятный для каждого, приятный друзьям – приятный для друзей, чуждые нам взгляды – чуждые для нас взгляды (***во всех этих сочетаниях предлог для подчеркивает связь с лицом – косвенным объектом).***

Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ
М.: ЧеРо, 1999

Comment: Очень интересно. Спасибо Серж!